# RegEx Get Error Message

Tags: c#, regex

I am new at RegEx and I was wondering if there is a way to display error messages to the user such as what he/she did wrong just by using RegEx. Is there some hypotetical RegEx.GetErroMessage thing? The user enters a string and I match it with my regex pattern, if there is no match i would like to show the error.

Let say i have such expression `^[0-9]{0,8}$`. As far I understood the expression I am telling to match on digits with number length less or equal 8. Now the problem is that user could have entered a letter or he/she entered more than 8 digits.

Can I get the error message somehow from RegEx or do I have to write my own for each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a message to be user-friendly, you have to write your own message for every RegEx check.

Even if Regex could point to specific character in input, message would be something spooky, like

```
Incorrect character at position 7 for expression ^[0-9]{0,8}$
```

A better option is to use masked input in your UI, so that user cannot enter anything, but digits.

Comment: This. To regex, it will never say "Your third character was an 'a', to therefore it does not match a number like it is supposed to", but rather "no, it doesn't match what I have. I don't care what it actually is, but it definitely doesn't match".

Comment: You even will have to write your own regex engine to find out *why* exactly the regex didn't match, *and* you'll have to anticipate all the possible errors *and* write all those error messages. Not really feasible IMO.